# Remove item from ComboBox (DropDownList) Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have a dropdownlist which has been populated

```
ddlNumbers.DisplayMember = "PhoneNumber";
ddlNumbers.DataSource = mobileList;
ddlNumbers.SelectedItem = null;
```

When a button is clicked I want to remove an item from it.

```
ddlMobileNumbers.Items.RemoveAt(i);
```

But get the exception. *'Items collection cannot be modified when the DataSource property is set...'*

I have also tried re-assigning a collection to the `DataSource`

```
ddlNumbers.DataSource = myNewList
```

But does not work.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't remove an item from a list when its bound to a control, You can temporarily `null` the data source of the bound control and remove the item from list and then set the data source again.

Something like,

```
//Null the datasource
Combobox1.Datasource = null;

//Remove the item
ddlMobileNumbers.Items.RemoveAt(i);

//Set the source again
Combobox1.Datasource = ddlMobileNumbers;
```

Comment: `List<Phone> contactList = (List<Phone>)ddlNumbers.DataSource;
ddlNumbers.DataSource = null;
contactList.RemoveAt(i);
ddlNumbers.DataSource = contactList;`

Like this? @AccessDenied